# JavaFX tableview colors

Tags: java, tableview, javafx

i need create JavaFx TableView with multicolor rows (color1 for low priority, color2 for medium priority etc.). I have created CellFactory

```
public class TaskCellFactory implements Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> {

@Override
public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

   TableCell cell = new TableCell<Task, Object>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : getString());
            setGraphic(null);
            TableRow currentRow = getTableRow();
            Task currentTask = currentRow == null ? null : (Task)currentRow.getItem();
            if(currentTask != null){   
                Priority priority = currentTask.getPriority();
                clearPriorityStyle();
                if(!isHover() && !isSelected() && !isFocused()){
                    setPriorityStyle(priority);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateSelected(boolean upd){
            super.updateSelected(upd);
            System.out.println("is update");
        }

        private void clearPriorityStyle(){
            ObservableList<String> styleClasses = getStyleClass();
            styleClasses.remove("priorityLow");
            styleClasses.remove("priorityMedium");
            styleClasses.remove("priorityHigh");
        }

        private void setPriorityStyle(Priority priority){
            switch(priority){
                case LOW:
                    getStyleClass().add("priorityLow");
                    break;
                case MEDIUM:
                    getStyleClass().add("priorityMedium");
                    break;
                case HIGH:
                    getStyleClass().add("priorityHigh");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(getStyleClass());
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    };
    return cell;
} }
```

and css

```
.priorityLow{ -fx-background-color: palegreen; }
.priorityMedium{ -fx-background-color: skyblue;}
.priorityHigh{ -fx-background-color: palevioletred;}
```

But i still need highlight selected rows. How can i do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of setting the background color for the entire cell in your css, just set the -fx-control-inner-background.  Then you will have the default accent, hover and focus rings still available.  Also remove the if statement around your `setPriorityStyle` call of course.

If you also want to override things like the default accent (selected) color or the hover color, you can also do this as in the css below - not sure if the highlight overrides are really recommended though, guess it would depend on your app and desired user experience.

```
.priorityLow { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: palegreen;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}

.priorityMedium { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: skyblue;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}

.priorityHigh { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: palevioletred;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}
```

[image: rowhighlight]

---

Detailed styling information for JavaFX can be found in the default [caspian.css stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) for JavaFX 2.2 and the [JavaFX 2 CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).  To find caspian.css for your version of JavaFX you can unjar `jfxrt.jar` (sometimes found in the jre/lib directory).

**Update**

The default stylesheet for JavaFX is now named `modena.css` rather than `caspian.css`.

Comment: Thanks you)) Can you answer, where can i find list of these css-properties (like -fx-control-inner-background, -fx-accent) or some samples?

Comment: I have another question: can i similarly highlight single cell in row?

Comment: Yes, set a a custom [cell factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) for the column containing the cell and in the cell factory provide cells which can manipulate their own style as required.  If you need more detail, post a new question and I'm sure you'll get further info on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes Aubin, appears the solution no longer works with Java 8...such a shame.