# How to change the row color based on data that can change in a tableview?

Tags: css, javafx-2, tableview, background-color

I am writing a podcast player and have a list of files that I display.

The user can double click an entry and that files play. If they select another one. I don’t know what has been selected in the list. The idea is to highlight the file that is playing in a different color. With still keeping the ability to select another file (don’t want to lose that functionality).  Most audio players work on the same principle.

I had a look at this [JavaFX tableview colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697115/javafx-tableview-colors) and this changes the color of the row based on data. But if the data changes the row color do not refresh as the data changes.

I have a table with cell factory and based on the variable "isSelectedFile" I set the cell style.

If the isSelectedFile=True at load time all is ok but once I change the data while the rows are loaded into the tableview it doesn't refresh.

My cell factory is as follows:

```
entryDisplayNameColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<PlaylistEntry, String>, TableCell<PlaylistEntry, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {

                TableCell cell = new TableCell<Task, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(empty ? null : getString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                        TableRow currentRow = getTableRow();
                        PlaylistEntry ple = currentRow == null ? null : (PlaylistEntry) currentRow.getItem();

                        if (ple != null) {
                            clearPriorityStyle();
                            setPriorityStyle(ple.isSelectedFile());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateSelected(boolean upd) {
                        super.updateSelected(upd);
                        System.out.println("is update");
                    }

                    private void clearPriorityStyle() {
                        ObservableList<String> styleClasses = getStyleClass();
                        styleClasses.remove("priorityLow");
                        styleClasses.remove("priorityMedium");
                        styleClasses.remove("priorityHigh");
                    }

                    private void setPriorityStyle(boolean activeValue) {
                        if (activeValue) {
                            getStyleClass().add("priorityLow");
                        } else {
                            getStyleClass().add("priorityMedium");
                        }
                    }

                    private String getString() {
                        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```

My CSS:

```
.priorityLow { 
-fx-control-inner-background: snow;
-fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
-fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}

.priorityMedium { 
-fx-control-inner-background: #1d1d1d;
-fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
-fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
 }
```

Comment: See if this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5470095) and the related question linked in the comments on the gist help to create a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this its perfectly worked...

```
tablecol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<CheckDo, String>, TableCell<CheckDo, String>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<CheckDo, String> call(TableColumn<CheckDo, String> p) {


             return new TableCell<CheckDo, String>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!isEmpty())
                    this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
                    this.getTableRow().setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
                        setText(item);
                }
            }
        };
```