# JavaFX 8 TableView Text Alignment

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-8

I have the same problem as in [JavaFX TableView text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455326/javafx-tableview-text-alignment), but old solution doesn't work with JavaFX 8. With code below, the cells are painted red, but alignment is still left. "-fx-text-alignment" doesn't work either.

**main.fxml (relevant fragment)**

```
<AggregatorTableView id="aggregators"/>
```

**styles.css**

```
#aggregators .table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

**AggregatorTableView.java**

```
public class AggregatorTableView extends TableView<Aggregator> {
    public AggregatorTableView() {
        TableColumn<Aggregator, Boolean> activeCol = new TableColumn<>("Active?");
        TableColumn<Aggregator, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Aggregator, String> resourceCol = new TableColumn<>("Resource");
        TableColumn<Aggregator, String> versionCol = new TableColumn<>("Version");
        activeCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> cdf.getValue().isActive());
        activeCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(activeCol));
        activeCol.setOnEditCommit(e -> e.getRowValue().isActive().set(e.getNewValue()));
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(cdf.getValue().getName()));
        resourceCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(cdf.getValue().getResource()));
        versionCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(cdf.getValue().getVersion()));
        getColumns().addAll(activeCol, nameCol, resourceCol, versionCol);
        setEditable(true);
        setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        getItems().add(new Aggregator() {
            private BooleanProperty isActive = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
            @Override public String getName() { return "test"; }
            @Override public String getVersion() { return "0.0.1"; }
            @Override public String getResource() { return "test.org"; }
            @Override public List<DataItem> receiveData() { return null; }
            @Override public BooleanProperty isActive() { return isActive; }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I face similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918636/tablecell-not-applied-consistently. Have posted on jira: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33372?focusedCommentId=368263&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-368263 in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The solution mentioned by @UlukBiy (here: [JavaFX TableView text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455326/javafx-tableview-text-alignment)) works for my, and I am using javaFX8.

I just defined my Tableview in FXML like this:

```
<TableView>
<columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="couponHash" text="Kortingscode">
    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="hashID" /></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn fx:id="couponTimeCreated" text="Aangemaakt op">
    <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="timestampCreated" /></cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn> 
</columns>
</TableView>
```

The FXML file is connected to a css file, where I only inserted this style class:

```
.table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;
}
```

This works for me with JavaFX8. Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code doing the same alignment:

```
    TableColumn sizeCol = new TableColumn("Size");
    sizeCol.setResizable(true);
    sizeCol.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;");
    sizeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Parameter, Long>("size"));
```

It worked for me, but I read an old post where someone said it didn't work for editing. I didn't test that out since my table is read only.