# Highlight TableView rows in JavaFX when Time cell is past current time

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I have searched online for the past few hours and have tried to implement this feature with no luck.

I have a TableView with various columns, one of which is a String field which holds a time. I want to highlight all the rows that have a `timeCol` value that is later than the current time.

This will have to be checked every 5 minutes and highlight the table accordingly.
I am assuming this will need to run on a background thread but I'm in-experienced with concurrency.

**TableView Content**

```
@FXML
private TableView<BookingImpl> bookingTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> timeCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> nameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> pickUpCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> dropOffCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> commentCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<BookingImpl, String> priceCol;
```

I have seen this post [JavaFX tableview colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697115/javafx-tableview-colors) which looks like what I want to achieve, The highlight colour needs to be palevioletred.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - James_D Solution**

I have adjusted this to fit my application, however it only highlights the late bookings on input, i.e. if I enter a booking 1 minute from now and wait it will not highlight it. 
I have disabled the FXML implementation of columns but would prefer to use it.

I am referencing this new class from my main controller class as follows;

```
TableRowController rowController = new TableRowController();
rowController.start(bookingTableView);
```

**TableRowController**

package Controllers;

```
import Model.BookingImpl;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TableRowController{

private final PseudoClass future = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("future");

public void start(TableView table){
    ObjectProperty<LocalTime> now = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(LocalTime.now());
    table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<BookingImpl> row = new TableRow<>();
        ChangeListener<LocalTime> listener = (obs, oldTime, newTime) -> updateRow(row, now.get());
        now.addListener(listener);
        row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (oldItem != null) {
                oldItem.getTimeProperty().removeListener(listener);
            }
            if (newItem != null) {
                newItem.getTimeProperty().addListener(listener);
            }
            updateRow(row, now.get());
        });
        return row ;
    });

    configureTable(table);
}

public void updateRow(TableRow<BookingImpl> row, LocalTime now) {
    boolean isFuture = false ;
    if (row.getItem() != null) {
        isFuture = row.getItem().getTime().isBefore(now);
    }
    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(future, isFuture);
}


private void configureTable(TableView<BookingImpl> table) {
    table.getColumns().add(column("Time", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<LocalTime>>) (t) -> t.getTimeProperty()));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Name", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<String>>) (t) -> new SimpleStringProperty(t.getClientName())));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Pickup", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<String>>) (t) -> new SimpleStringProperty(t.getPickUpAddress())));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Dropoff", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<String>>) (t) -> new SimpleStringProperty(t.getDropOffAddress())));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Comment", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<String>>) (t) -> new SimpleStringProperty(t.getComments())));
    table.getColumns().add(column("Price", (Function<BookingImpl, Property<String>>) (t) -> new SimpleStringProperty(t.getFormattedPrice())));
    table.setItems(ObservableLists.bookingsList);
}

private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
    TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    return column ;
}

}
```

**BookingImpl Class**

```
public class BookingImpl implements Booking {
public static int bookingNumberCounter = 1001;
private final int bookingNumber;
private Account account;
private String vehicleType;
private String noPassengers;
private LocalDate date;
private ObjectProperty<LocalTime> time = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
private String pickUpAddress;
private String dropOffAddress;
private String clientName;
private String clientTel;
private String clientEmail;
private String comments;
private double price;
private boolean completed = false;
private Driver driver;

public BookingImpl(Account account){
    this.bookingNumber = bookingNumberCounter;
    bookingNumberCounter++;
    Archive.allBookings.add(this);
    Archive.incompleteBookings.add(this);
    ObservableLists.bookingsList.clear();
    ObservableLists.bookingsList.addAll(Archive.incompleteBookings);
    account.newBooking(this);
}


@Override
public void deleteBooking() {
    account.deleteBooking(this);
    Archive.allBookings.remove(this);
}

public int getBookingNumber() {
    return bookingNumber;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public String getVehicleType() {
    return vehicleType;
}

public void setVehicleType(String vehicleType) {
    this.vehicleType = vehicleType;
}

public String getNoPassengers() {
    return noPassengers;
}

public void setNoPassengers(String noPassengers) {
    this.noPassengers = noPassengers;
}

public String getDate() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
}

public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public ObjectProperty<LocalTime> getTimeProperty() {
    return time;
}

public LocalTime getTime() {
    return this.getTimeProperty().get();
}

public void setTime(LocalTime time) {this.time.set(time);}

public String getPickUpAddress() {
    return pickUpAddress;
}

public void setPickUpAddress(String pickUpAddress) {
    this.pickUpAddress = pickUpAddress;
}

public String getDropOffAddress() {
    return dropOffAddress;
}

public void setDropOffAddress(String dropOffAddress) {
    this.dropOffAddress = dropOffAddress;
}

public String getClientName() {
    return clientName;
}

public void setClientName(String clientName) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
}

public String getClientTel() {
    return clientTel;
}

public void setClientTel(String clientTel) {
    this.clientTel = clientTel;
}

public String getClientEmail() {
    return clientEmail;
}

public void setClientEmail(String clientEmail) {
    this.clientEmail = clientEmail;
}

public String getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getFormattedPrice() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    return "£"+df.format(this.price);
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}

public Driver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
}
```

Comment: "A `String` field which holds a time..." Wouldn't it make more sense to use a `LocalTime` instead of a `String`?

Comment: Hi, this can be changed to `LocalTime` without an issue. Type is actually `Date` but saved to a string field.

Comment: Your cell value factories look wrong. Is your `BookingImpl` class using JavaFX properties? Also, where are you calling `start()`?

Comment: You need to implement your model class with [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) so that they can be properly observed. (I.e. implement `BookingImpl` using the same pattern I used for `Item`.)

Comment: Only the `LocalTime` field uses the JavaFX properties, `start()` is being called from my main controller class in the `initialize()` method. Will adjust the class as advised, hopefully it works :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Then that should work (for that column). I don't see where you ever update the current time though. What is going to cause `now` to change?

Comment: I have adjusted all fields either be `StringProperty` or `ObjectProperty<>` but still no luck.  Shouldn't `now` always be the current time? as its wrapped in a `ObjectProperty`?

Comment: Again, I don't see anywhere that you update the current time (`now`). If you don't ever change it, it won't be the current time, and the listener will not get called.

Comment: I did not see this in the code you provided, where did you update `now` in your example?

Comment: As I said in the text "update it from an AnimationTimer". It's set up in the startClock() method.

Comment: It works !! you are a star! thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as follows:

Use a `rowFactory` on the table. The row you create will observe the current item's time property, and update a CSS PseudoClass if it changes. You also need the row to observe the current time: to do this create a `ObjectProperty<LocalTime>` and update it from an `AnimationTimer`.

The advantage of using a CSS PseudoClass is that you can define the style in an external CSS file.

Here is an example:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightFutureItems extends Application {

    private final PseudoClass future = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("future");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();

        ObjectProperty<LocalTime> now = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(LocalTime.now());

        startClock(now);

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            ChangeListener<LocalTime> listener = (obs, oldTime, newTime) -> updateRow(row, now.get());
            now.addListener(listener);
            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    oldItem.timeProperty().removeListener(listener);
                }
                if (newItem != null) {
                    newItem.timeProperty().addListener(listener);
                }
                updateRow(row, now.get());
            });
            return row ;
        });

        configureTable(table);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Label clock = new Label();
        root.setTop(clock);

        clock.textProperty().bind(now.asString());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("future-highlighting-table.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateRow(TableRow<Item> row, LocalTime now) {
        boolean isFuture = false ;
        if (row.getItem() != null) {
            isFuture = row.getItem().getTime().isAfter(now);
        }
        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(future, isFuture);
    }

    private void startClock(ObjectProperty<LocalTime> clock) {
        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long timestamp) {
                clock.set(LocalTime.now());
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void configureTable(TableView<Item> table) {
        table.getColumns().add(column("Item", Item::nameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Time", Item::timeProperty));

        Random rng = new Random();
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 50 ; i++) {
            Item item = new Item("Item "+i, now.plusSeconds(rng.nextInt(120) - 60));
            table.getItems().add(item);
        }
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return column ;
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalTime> time = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Item(String name, LocalTime time) {
            setName(name);
            setTime(time);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final ObjectProperty<LocalTime> timeProperty() {
            return this.time;
        }


        public final LocalTime getTime() {
            return this.timeProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setTime(final LocalTime time) {
            this.timeProperty().set(time);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The CSS file (`future-highlighting-table.css"`) can be as simple as

```css
.table-row-cell:future {
    -fx-background: palevioletred;
}
```

Comment: Excellent example! this will work great for me I really appreciate your answer @James_D

Comment: I noticed you have used `<Item>` as the table type, I have tried to change this to `<BookingImpl>` and refactor the code but I have been running into issues with it. Do I have to use `<Item>` for the TableView?

Comment: No, of course not. Item is just the name of the class I defined in the example.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried my best to get it working but having issues with it highlighting after input. I have edited my original post to include the code.